# Get user age_range with gigya

Tags: facebook, gigya

Using the socialize.getUserInfo for the 2.0 version of the Facebook API doesn't return the age_range attribute.

Is there a way to get the age_range with gigya and avoid asking the user for the age extra permission?

I'm reading the docs here: http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/socialize.getUserInfo

But I can't find any clues on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gigya only pulls back data from the social provider that has been made available to it and that [Gigya maps internally](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/010_Objects/User_object).  Gigya currently does not map the `age_range` so this value will not ever be returned with the call to `socialize.getUserInfo`.

Instead, to return this data using Gigya, you must use the `socialize.facebookGraphOperation` [endpoint](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/socialize.facebookGraphOperation) to request the Facebook Graph endpoint `/profile` that would allow you to return this data. This means that you also need to configure your Facebook Application (under the facebook developers console) to request the ***age*** extra permission.

Comment: Yeah that sucks. We chose to ask the user for their age on the NatGeo site.